# Java - How to get items out of a list with String Arrays

Tags: java, list, get

How do I get a specific item out of a "List" at a specific index?

```
private List<String[]> rows;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `get(i)` with the list and `[j]` for array :

```
String value = rows.get(i)[j];
```

In your case `rows.get(i)` return a `String[]`, then `[j]` will return a String with the index `j`.

---

For more details, I will invite you to learn about :

- [**Arrays**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [**List**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Answer (score 2):

RTFM for the [List class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)

All the methods are listed and explained there, e.g.: [get(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#get(int)):

> *Returns the element at the specified position in this list.*

Also recommended: [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `enhanced for loop` to get items

```
for (String row: rows) {
    //  do what you want

    // ...
}
```